# Line break after a line containing specific Word

Tags: c#

The sample format which I have is mentioned below

-----------------------------------------------SAMPLE INPUT----------------------------------------

> **THE FREE LANCE**
>   Address: street View 1
>   Contact person: John Mattew
>   **TEST COMPANY 2**
>   ADDRESS 2
>   Contact Person: Jaskson Samuel
>
> **THE MASTER TEST COMPANY**
>   Address: street View 2
>   Contact Person: Jackson Sam
>   **THE MASTERMIND WORKING**
>   Contact Person: Simon Teo
>
> **FIVESTAR COMPANY**
>   Address: street View 3
>   Contact Person: Mr Edmund Long

-----------------------------------------------SAMPLE INPUT END--------------------------------------

I want the following output

-----------------SAMPLE OUTPUT ------------------------------

> **THE FREE LANCE**|Address: street View 1|Contact person: John Mattew ***$*** **TEST COMPANY 2**|ADDRESS 2|Contact Person: Jaskson Samuel ***$*** **THE MASTER TEST COMPANY**|Address: street View 2|Contact Person: Jackson Sam ***$*** **THE MASTERMIND WORKING**|Contact Person: Simon Teo ***$*** **FIVESTAR COMPANY**|Address: street View 3|Contact Person: Mr Edmund Long

-----------------SAMPLE OUTPUT END ------------------------------

I tried using replace function and replace /r/n with | but confused about how to add $ before every Company. The only thing I observe is the last line of each lead ends with contact person along with name. Please help me identity code to do the following

Comment: its `\r\n` not `/r/n` for starters.. and it's not difficult to add `$` before the company.. can you show the existing code that you are using .? also for the input.. are you splitting on any delimiters ??

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` better :)

Comment: The sample input, is this 1 long string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do it :)
Heres one possible way.

**A suggestion**

If there is always 2 rows per company for instance: **Address** and **Contact Person**.

Then you can loop through each line and keep count for how many lines parsed and then use that to find the company name, then the rest will solve itself.

Example:

```
public class CompanyInfo {
    public string Name {get;set;} 
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public string ContactPerson {get;set;}
    public override string ToString() {
        return "$ " + Name + "|" + Address + "|" + ContactPerson;
    }
}

public string ParseInput(string input, int rowsPerCompany=3) {
   var companies = new List<CompanyInfo>();
   var rows = input.Split('\n');
   var tmpIndex=0; 
   var lined = new List<string>();
   CompanyInfo lastCompany = null;
   for(var j = 0; j < rows.Length; j++) {
      // Skip any rows that starts with ----
      if(rows[j].Trim().StartsWith("----")) { 
         lined.Add(rows[j]); continue; 
      }

      if(tmpIndex==0) {
         lastCompany = new CompanyInfo();
         lastCompany.Name = rows[j];
      }
      if(tmpIndex==rowsPerCompany) {
         tmpIndex=0;
         companies.Add(lastCompany);
      }
      else{
         if(tmpIndex==0) { lastCompany.Name = rows[j]; }
         if(tmpIndex==1) { lastCompany.Address= rows[j]; }
         if(tmpIndex==2) { lastCompany.ContactPerson = rows[j]; }
         tmpIndex++;
      }
   }
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.AppendLine(lined.FirstOrDefault());

   sb.AppendLine(string.Join("", companies.Select(c=>c.ToString()).ToArray() ));
   sb.AppendLine(lined.LastOrDefault());
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

Please note that the code is not tested.

Hope this is for any help / Answered your question.

Cheers,
Zerratar